# Carbon monoxide treatment

Tags: organic-chemistry

When CO is the by product of certain reactions( burning of coal under limited air supply), how is it treated before releasing in the atmosphere or is it converted to some other form? Can that byproduct be used to synthesize some other compound ?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, production scale processes are highly optimized, producing just traces of $\ce{CO}$. There traces are either not managed, or can by passed through catalyzators.

On the other hand, burning coke with limited air or oxygen $\ce{2 C(s) + O2(g) -> 2 CO(s)}$ or passing water vapour through burning coke $\ce{C(s) + H2O(g) -> CO(g) + H2(g)}$, are used intentionally, to produce $\ce{CO}$, eventually with hydrogen, for further synthesis.

Answer (score 0):

> - Scrubbing by a highly corrosive copper chloride solution. The industrial application of this method has long been discontinued. (See [this patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US2519284A/en) for more information)
> - Catalytically converting $\ce{CO}$ into $\ce{CO2}$, according to the [water gas    shift reaction.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water-gas_shift_reaction)
> - Catalytic methanation of $\ce{CO}$ with hydrogen to methane, forming a    synthetic natural gas.
> - Scrubbing with liquid nitrogen

Source: https://www.eolss.net/Sample-Chapters/C09/E4-14-02-01.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The need to do something about CO emission and the methods used to reduce the emissions depend strongly on the circumstances.

Poutnik is right that large scale processes will be both optimised and designed to minimise emissions, there are other, different, mechanisms and solutions in other processes.

A major example is vehicles whose engines produce notable amounts of CO because combustion is never fully controlled and where the optimal power output, efficiency and emissions of other pollutants leave notable amounts of CO in the exhaust gases. Modern cars use a variety of types of catalytic converter in the exhaust path to minimise the ultimate CO released.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question: "how is it treated before releasing in the atmosphere or is it converted to some other form?", a direct answer is that a significant part (if not a majority) of the created carbon monoxide is not treated.  Hence, reported significant poor air quality issues in select locales, as per a featured story, [Helping China Fight Air Pollution](https://www.worldbank.org/en/news/feature/2018/06/11/helping-china-fight-air-pollution#:%7E:text=Coal%20is%20the%20single%2Dlargest,66%25%20of%20the%20energy%20mix.&text=Reducing%20coal%20consumption%20through%20improved,key%20to%20clearing%20the%20air), as an example, to quote:

> Coal is the single-largest source of air pollutants and greenhouse emissions in China. The country heavily relies on coal to meet its energy demand at 66% of the energy mix. China consumed approximately 4 billion tons of coal in 2014— more than the rest of the world combined. Half of China’s coal is used for decentralized boilers in the industrial and residential sectors.

However, courtesy of the following photochemical reaction naturally occurring in the atmosphere, some mitigation occurring, to quote from a [Science Direct source](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/earth-and-planetary-sciences/photochemical-reaction):

> The prevailing view is that $\ce{CO}$ is oxidized by $\ce{.OH}$ via

> $\ce{ CO + .OH -> CO2 + .H}$

> The $\ce{.OH}$ itself is ultimately derived from the photolysis of water vapor. Thus, even though water vapor is a minor constituent, it may play a very important role in maintaining $\ce{CO2}$ as the dominant constituent. Support for the importance of this water chemistry comes from the detection of molecular hydrogen ($\ce{H2)}$ in the atmosphere and the distribution and abundance of ozone.

I would also note more commonly occurring in the surface waters on earth as a matter of academic interest ([as detailed here](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fmars.2016.00217/full) and not commercial paths), reactive oxygen species including the hydroxyl radical can be formed in a Fenton (or [Fenton-type](https://www.journal.csj.jp/doi/pdf/10.1246/bcsj.55.666)) reaction of transition metal salts (like with a soluble cuprous complex) with acidic hydrogen peroxide (or $\ce{H2O2}$ as sourced from oxygen). Or relatedly, per the above-cited atmospheric chemistry, one can even replace photolysis with sonolysis of the water (which jointly creates $\ce{.H}$ and $\ce{.OH}$).